# Conflict bootstrap css with other css stylesheets

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, stylesheet, conflict

I have a problem with combining few css stylesheets with bootstrap. I found that this piece of bootstrap css code make me a problem.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When I comment this code my css menu and slide images works fine but then other elements with bootstrap classes look weird. All stylsheets are included after bootstrap.

This is my image slider css code in featured.css and looks OK when I comment code above, which is located in a bootstrap stylsheet

```css
#featured { 
 width:870px;
 padding-right:280px; 
 position:relative; 
 border:10px solid #141b1b; 
 height:420px; 
 background: #D3D3D3;
}
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav { 
 position:absolute; 
 top:0; left:835px; 
 list-style:none; 
 padding:0;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-top: 0;
 width:315px; 
 z-index: 100;
}
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav li { 
 padding: 0; padding-left: 15px;
 margin: 0;
 font-size:12px; 
 color:#666; 
}
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav li img { 
 float:left;
 background: #FFF; 
 margin-right: 5px;
 padding: 4px; 
 border:1px solid #999;
}
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav li span { 
 font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana; 
 line-height:18px;
 width: 300px;

}
#featured li.ui-tabs-nav-item a { 
 display:block; 
 padding: 5px 5px;
 margin: 0;
 height: 60px; 
 color: #333;
 line-height:20px;
}
#featured li.ui-tabs-nav-item a:hover { 
 background:#FFF; 
}
#featured li.ui-tabs-selected { 
 background: url(../images/slider_hover.png) no-repeat;  
}
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a { 
}
#featured .ui-tabs-panel { 
 width:660px; height:350px; 
 background:#FFF; position:relative;
}
#featured .ui-tabs-panel .info { 
 position:absolute; 
 top:320px; left:0; 
 width: 850px;
 height:100px; 
 background: url('../images/transparent-bg.png'); 
}
#featured .info h2 { 
 font-size:18px; font-family:Georgia, serif; 
 color:#fff; padding:5px; margin:0;
 overflow:hidden; 
}
#featured .info p { 
 margin:0 5px; 
 font-family:Verdana; font-size:11px; 
 line-height:15px; color:#f0f0f0;
}
#featured .info a { 
 text-decoration:none; 
 color:#fff; 
}
#featured .info a:hover { 
 text-decoration:underline; 
}
#featured .ui-tabs-hide { 
 display:none; 
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: * Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Please [edit] your question to be more specific about what error is occurring and enough code for us to see it.

Comment: A [runnable Stack Overflow snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers/269810) (the icon with angle brackets on a sheet of paper) is preferable but if you'd rather not, you can just format your code like jarasss did below (the icon with curly braces).

Comment: Anyway: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Thanks Scott. I realized. With star before brackets box-size doesn't count paddings and borders. Problem is solved. Thanks for link.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1. Maybe you should prefix your "additional classes" so they don't clash with bootstrap's? http://www.css-prefix.com/

Option 2. If you are sure that classes that clash are only those you mentioned I recommend doing something like that:

```
.your-css-menu-class-name {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;  // this is default value
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

The best would be if you could create jsfiddle and show me full example http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This is css from slide sheet. There is no same class name.
https://jsfiddle.net/0mc6s4np/1/